# Angular2 back button issue | URL not changing | Angular Universal

Tags: angular, typescript, browser-history, angular-routing, html5-history

Its kinda weird problem but I dunno what's going on. When I click the back browser button, the page changes but the `URL` remains the same. When I click the back button again, the `URL` changes but the page remains the same.

This was fixed after using

```
window.history.pushState({},'',url);
```

but with this... the problem is that I loop around 2 pages if I keep clicking back button.

EXAMPLE :-

```
A -> B -> C -> (back) -> B -> (back) -> C -> (back) -> B -> (back) -> C-> (back) -> B -> (back)
```

NOTE :-
    I have RouterModule.forRoot() in root routing module and RouterModule.forChild() in child routes.

I am using [angular universal](https://github.com/angular/universal-starter).

What could be the possible issue? How can this be solved?

----------------------------------- XXXXXX -----------------------------------------------

UPDATE

```
Was playing with code and i ran into Location of @angular/common. 
This is great with popstate (resolved the url change issue) but the problem now is...
whenever i hit back button...it pop same page twice....
```

EXAMPLE :-

```
A -> B -> C -> (back) -> B -> (back) -> B -> (back) -> A -> (back) -> A
```

----------------------------------- XXXXXX -----------------------------------------------

UPDATE 2:-

```
when using location.. i checked the history length... 
the history length is not changing when the back button is clicked first time...
```

EXAMPLE :-

```
A : length = 1 -> B : length = 2 -> C : length = 3 -> (back) -> B : length = 3 -> (back) -> 
B : length = 2 -> (back) -> A : length = 2 -> (back) -> A : length = 1
```

P.S. -> Check the link before asking for library versions.

Comment: may be i'm not know angular anought but "window.history.pushState({},'',url);" not looks angular to me... anyway - what code you using to navigate between pages?

Comment: @happyZZR1400 should have checked the link before asking......... well since you asked... its angular code... i used routerlink to travel between pages....... (routerlinks are like href)...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the file

> app-routing.module.ts

and make sure that the imported routes are like

```
RouterModule.forChild([])
```

rather than

```
RouterModule.forRoot([])
```

It will solve the issue.